# How to change parameter in URL iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, urlencode, encode, nsurl

I have a URL like `myApp://action/1?parameter=2&secondparameter=3&thirdparameter=10`

I need to change parameter = 2
and secondparameter =3 like `myApp://action/1?parameter=10&secondparameter=15&thirdparameter=10`

**Any ideas**

Thx a lot

Comment: can you show some code where you use this URL.

Comment: Change it using what? I'm guessing you want to do it in some form of code?

Comment: Is it just a string or its in URLrequest

Comment: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];` and myURL is Url with some change parameter

Comment: i want to change my parameters `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {parameter = 2;} else parameter = 1`

Comment: So you want to change that parameters dynamically means depend on other value right?

Comment: Dilip, it is a string

Comment: yes, if iPad it will be 3 if iPhone 4.

Comment: i need to parse string and than change the value of parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *myURL    

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
    NSString * parameter =@"2";
    NSString * secondparameter =@"3";

    myURL =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myApp://action/1?parameter=%@&secondparameter=%@&thirdparameter=10",parameter,secondparameter];

    }
    else
    {
    NSString * parameter =@"10";
    NSString * secondparameter =@"15";

    myURL =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myApp://action/1?parameter=%@&secondparameter=%@&thirdparameter=10",parameter,secondparameter];

    }
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
```

Try this code...

Comment: it's work fine but maybe exists another way how make it. because if my url will have more parameters

Comment: So you are saying that you URL is not predefined?

Comment: yes,i know than i need to change only 2 parameters from 6 or 10 ( i don't know how much)

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you need to perform this on an arbitrary URL, so the steps are:

1. Break the query down into something you can work with, i.e. a dictionary
2. Mutate the query dictionary
3. Construct a new URL with the new query

I maintain the [KSFileUtilities](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities) repository. The [KSURLQueryUtilities](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities/blob/master/KSURLQueryUtilities.h) routines will help you easily achieve the above.